# prove (or disprove) $\left|x^\top\left(\frac{x}{|x|^\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{y+x}{|y+x|^\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right|\le 3|x||y|^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

As stated in the title, I need help showing (or disproving) $$\left|x^\top\left(\frac{x}{|x|^\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{y+x}{|y+x|^\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right|\le 3|x||y|^\frac{1}{2}$$ for $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

Here, we take $|\cdot|$ to be the Euclidean norm and we interpret $\frac{x}{|x|^\frac{1}{2}}$ to be $0$ at $x=0$. I have already shown it to be true for scalar x, y but I am having trouble proving (or disproving) it for the vector valued case. I tried several approaches including inducting on the dimension, finding scalars $\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}$ corresponding to $x$ and $y$ (with $|\tilde{x}|<|x|$ and $|\tilde{y}|<|y|$) and upper bounding the vector valued expression by the scalar one, but none of these approaches have really panned out for me. I even wrote a MATLAB script to look for a counter example but cannot find one so far. This problem is relevant to a research problem I am working on so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

(EDIT: it should be noted that it may possible one could improve the 3 with a smaller constant, but at the moment I can't find an optimal value. However, for my purposes showing the statement with any constant in place of the 3 will suffice)

Comment: How is $x^\top$ defined?

Comment: @popoolmica that's the transpose of $x$

Comment: I think that you can reduce to the case where $x=(\vert x\vert, 0, \dots, 0)$ using the fact that the euclidean norm is invariant under rotation. That might simplify the problem a bit and makes it almost $1$-dimensional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you allow it, here’s a proof with a weaker constant 5 instead of 3.

Let $a = |x|$, $b = \langle x,y\rangle$, and $c = |y|$. If $a \leq 4c$, then we can use Cauchy-Schwarz to bound the quantity by
\begin{align*}
|x| \cdot \left\lvert \frac{x}{|x|^{1/2}} - \frac{y+x}{|y+x|^{1/2}} \right\rvert \leq |x|\cdot (|x|^{1/2} + |y+x|^{1/2}) \leq a \cdot (2a ^{1/2} + c^{1/2}) \leq a\cdot (2\sqrt 4+1)c^{1/2} = 5a c^{1/2}.
\end{align*}
We thus assume $a > 4c$. Note that
$$
\left\langle x, \frac{x}{|x|^{1/2}} - \frac{y+x}{|y+x|^{1/2}}\right\rangle = a^{3/2} - \frac{b+a^2}{(a^2 + 2b + c^2)^{1/4}}
$$
We will show that the second term is convex in $b$. Indeed, the first derivative with respect to $b$ is
$$
\frac{(a^2+2b+c^2)^{1/4} - \frac12 (a^2+b) (a^2+2b+c^2)^{-3/4}} {(a^2+2b+c^2)^{2/4}} = (a^2+2b+c^2)^{-1/4} - \frac12 \frac{a^2+b}{(a^2+2b+c^2)^{5/4}}
$$
and the second derivative with respect to $b$ is
\begin{align*}
&-\frac12(a^2+2b+c^2)^{-5/4} - \frac12\frac{(a^2+2b+c^2)^{5/4} - 2\cdot\frac54(a^2+b)(a^2+2b+c^2)^{1/4}}{(a^2+2b+c^2)^{10/4}} \\
=&~ -(a^2+2b+c^2)^{-5/4} + \frac54\frac{a^2+b}{(a^2+2b+c^2)^{9/4}} \\
=&~ -(a^2+2b+c^2)^{-5/4} + \frac54\frac{a^2+b}{(a^2+2b+c^2)^{9/4}} + \frac54\frac{c^2+b}{(a^2+2b+c^2)^{9/4}} - \frac54\frac{c^2+b}{(a^2+2b+c^2)^{9/4}} \\
=&~ \frac14\frac{1}{(a^2+2b+c^2)^{5/4}} - \frac54\frac{c^2+b}{(a^2+2b+c^2)^{9/4}} \\
\end{align*}
This is positive as long as
$$
a^2+2b+c^2 \geq 5(c^2+b)
$$
or
$$
a^2-3b+(9/4)c^2 \geq (25/4)c^2
$$
Note that $|b| \leq ac$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, so this is true if $(a-(3/2)c)^2 \geq (25/4)c^2$, or $a \geq 4c$.

Now, we know that $(b+a^2)/(a^2+2b+c^2)^{1/4}$ is convex, so it is largest or smallest at its endpoints $|b| = ac$ or its critical point. At the end points of $|b| = ac$, this means that $\langle x,y\rangle = |x||y|$, so $x$ and $y$ have to be in the same direction, and this reduces to the 1-dimensional problem, which you have already solved. It remains to check the critical point.

When the derivative is $0$, we have $(a^2+2b+c^2)^{-1/4} = (a^2+b)(a^2+2b+c^2)^{-5/4}/2$, or $b = -(a^2+2c^2)/3$. However, note that we restricted $|b| \leq ac \leq a^2/4$. Thus, this critical point is infeasible, so we dismiss this case and conclude.

Comment: Actually, it seems you can simplify the proof and improve the constant a bit by showing that the first derivative is positive whenever $a\geq 3c$, by similar reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However, I think there is a small error in the computation of the first derivative (so also the second derivative), as it should be replaced with the negative of what you wrote. This would imply that $(b+a^2)/(a^2+2b+c^2)^{1/4}$ is concave for $a\ge 4c$, but I think the result will still hold since a concave function also achieves its extrema at a critical point or the end points

Comment: Right, I don't think it matters since we need to find both minima and maxima because of the absolute value. In any case, it seems like we don't actually even need to check convexity/concavity, since the function is just monotone on the interval we care about.

Comment: I see, thanks! I was able to build off of your solution and show that $T=a^\frac{3}{2}-(b+a^2)/(a^2+2b+c^2)^{1/4}$ is monotonic in $b$ for $a\ge c$, which results in the constant of 3. To do this, we let $a=nc$ and first show $\frac{\partial T}{\partial b}<0$ for n=1 (simplify and use Cauchy Schwarz). Then, we can show $\frac{\partial T}{\partial b}$ decreases in $n$ when $n>0$, and the rest follows. Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: That sounds great!

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove a stronger inequality:
$$\left|x^\top\left(\frac{x}{|x|^\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{y+x}{|y+x|^\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right|\le 2|x||y|^\frac{1}{2}. \tag{1}$$

The non-trivial case is that $x \ne 0$ and $x + y \ne 0$.

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, it suffices to prove that
$$|x|^2 \cdot \left|\frac{x}{|x|^\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{y+x}{|y+x|^\frac{1}{2}}\right|^2\le 4|x|^2|y|. \tag{2}$$

It suffices to prove that
$$ \left|\frac{x}{|x|^\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{y+x}{|y+x|^\frac{1}{2}}\right|^2\le 4|y|$$
or
$$|x| + |y + x| - \frac{2(x^\top y + |x|^2)}{|x|^{1/2}|x+y|^{1/2}} \le 4|y|. \tag{3}$$

Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have $x^\top y \ge -|x|\cdot |y|$. It suffices to prove that
$$|x| + |y + x| - \frac{2(-|x|\cdot |y| + |x|^2)}{|x|^{1/2}|x+y|^{1/2}} \le 4|y|. \tag{4}$$

Let
$$a := |x|^{1/2}, \quad b := |y|^{1/2}, \quad c := |y + x|^{1/2}.$$
Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality and $|x + y|^2 = |x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2x^\top y$, we have
$$a^4 + b^4 - 2a^2b^2 \le c^4 \le a^4 + b^4 + 2a^2b^2$$
which gives
$$\sqrt{|a^2 - b^2|} \le c \le \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}. \tag{5}$$

(4) is written as
$$a^2 + c^2 - \frac{2(-a^2b^2 + a^4)}{ac} \le 4b^2. \tag{6}$$

From (6), it suffices to prove that
$$-c^3 + (-a^2 + 4b^2)c + 2a^3 - 2ab^2 \ge 0. \tag{7}$$

From (5), using $c^2 \le a^2 + b^2$, it suffices to prove that
$$-c\cdot (a^2 + b^2) + (-a^2 + 4b^2)c + 2a^3 - 2ab^2 \ge 0$$
or
$$2a(a^2 - b^2) - (2a^2 - 3b^2)c \ge 0. \tag{8}$$

If $2a^2 - 3b^2 \le 0$, from (5), it suffices to prove that
$$2a(a^2 - b^2) - (2a^2 - 3b^2)\sqrt{|a^2 - b^2|} \ge 0$$
which is true (easy).

If $2a^2 - 3b^2 > 0$, from (5), it suffices to prove that
$$2a(a^2 - b^2) - (2a^2 - 3b^2)\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \ge 0$$
which is true (easy).

We are done.

Answer (score 2):

*Remarks*: I think that $\sqrt 2$ is the best constant. It is not proved yet.

**Problem**. Let $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be vectors with $x \ne 0$ and $x + y \ne 0$. Prove that
$$\left|x^\top\left(\frac{x}{|x|^\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{y+x}{|y+x|^\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right|\le \sqrt 2\,|x||y|^\frac{1}{2}.$$
Here, $|x| = \sqrt{x^\mathsf{T}x}$ is the Euclidean norm.

**proof**.

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, it suffices to prove that
$$|x|^2 \cdot \left|\frac{x}{|x|^\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{y+x}{|y+x|^\frac{1}{2}}\right|^2\le 2|x|^2|y|.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$ \left|\frac{x}{|x|^\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{y+x}{|y+x|^\frac{1}{2}}\right|^2\le 2|y|$$
or
$$|x| + |y + x| - \frac{2(x^\top y + |x|^2)}{|x|^{1/2}|x+y|^{1/2}} \le 2|y|$$
or
$$|x| + \sqrt{|x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2x^\mathsf{T} y} - \frac{2(x^\top y + |x|^2)}{|x|^{1/2}\sqrt[4]{|x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2x^\mathsf{T} y}} \le 2|y|. \tag{1}$$

WLOG, assume that $|x| = 1$.
Let $b: = |y|$ and $u := x^\mathsf{T}y$.
Then $- b \le u \le b$.

We need to prove that
$$1 + \sqrt{1 + b^2 + 2u} - \frac{2(u + 1)}{\sqrt[4]{1 + b^2 + 2u}} \le 2b. \tag{2}$$

If $b = 1$, true (easy).

If $b \ne 1$, letting $v = \sqrt[4]{1 + b^2 + 2u}$,
we have $\sqrt{|b - 1|} \le v \le \sqrt{b + 1}$.
It suffices to prove that
$$1 + v^2 - \frac{v^4 + 1 - b^2}{v} \le 2b$$
which is true (not difficult).

We are done.